# Why is custom slack app showing a gif just once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, slack, slack-commands

I'm trying to create a slack app in node js to send custom gifs (Simpson’s gifs) but slack is only showing each gif once per channel, not sure if this is a code issue or a configuration issue, the repo for the app is [Simpson's Gifs](http://httpshere%20https://github.com/Amagon96/simpsons-gifs)

Any idea?

Comment: What happens in your API when you call it 4 times in one channel ?

Comment: I mean, can you console.log the response in your postToChannel fetch request ?

Comment: @Zerowiel the first time it shows a gif with a message 'gif submitted by: user', the second time if the gif is the same just shows the message, so is only showing the gif when this one has not been displayed yet, and in the console.log I'm not seeing anything weird, is the same output on all scenarios

Comment: What happens if you try to submit manually (from slack) 2 same gif ?

Comment: Oh god, is all slack fault! I'm so happy and mad at this moment, thank you very much bro

Answer (score 0):

It was slack fault :face_pal:
Thanks @Zerowiel!

Comment: Yeah, that's what i tough. What was the problem ? Slack configuration ?

Comment: I think is slack default behavior, I couldn't find a configuration for that.